# Merge functionality from 2 jQuery snippets

Tags: jquery, wordpress, facetwp

I have 2 jQuery snippets that perform related things.

The first is this.

```
$(document).on('click', "[class*='fs-']", function(e) {
    var c = $(this).attr('class');  // I read the class of the element 
    c = c.slice(c.indexOf('fs-')) // I delete any classes prior to the desired one 
    .split(' ')[0]              // I delete any classes following the desired one
    .slice('fs-'.length);     // I delete the "fs" from the class 
    $("[data-value="+ c +"]").click();  // If the element exists, then it simulates a click on it. 
});
```

The effect of this code is to take the 'sliced' class of a clicked element and find another element with a matching class and click it.

The second jQuery snippet is this.

```
$(".show-welcome").click(function () {
        $.each(FWP.facets, function(name, val) {FWP.facets[name] = [];}); /* clear all */
        FWP.facets['chapter'] = ['welcome']; /* make selection */
        FWP.is_reset = true; // don't parse facets
        FWP.refresh();
});
```

This snippet acts on the javascript engine of the plugin FacetWP for Wordpress and in effect it has the effect of clearing all facets and then making a pre defined selection from a single facet. In this case it selects the option 'welcome' from the facet 'chapter'.

So I need to ad the same kind of dynamic quality to this second snippet. It might look something like this...

```
$(".show-XXX").click(function () {
        $.each(FWP.facets, function(name, val) {FWP.facets[name] = [];}); /* clear all */
        FWP.facets['chapter'] = ["the clicked element less the 'show-' part"]; /* make selection */
        FWP.is_reset = true; // don't parse facets
        FWP.refresh();
});
```

Can anyone tell me how I might achieve this? Many thanks.

OUTCOME

So in trying code provided by @Reflective I am finding that FacetWP is reacting twice to the click. That's the only way I have to describe it. Please see images attached.

My clickable element has the classes .chapter .show-designs-four-a

[image]

Comment: What's the actual problem? Write a function that returns the (first) class that starts with a given prefix.

Comment: [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: The problem is that i don't know how to do that. Could you possible help?

Comment: It's literally already in your question o.O Although there are (imho) better ways (see my second comment)

Comment: Simple - `this.classList`, but keep in mind it is a read-only oproperty

Comment: I appreciate the comments but I am simply not equipped to write this code myself. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Ok, I have given a possible answer (if I correctly understand the problem) with some light description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: Second part included!**

```js
$(function(){

  $(document).on('click', "[class*='fs-']", function(e) {
    // getting all classes and converting them to an array
    Array.from($(this).prop('classList'))
      // filtering non 'fs-' classes 
      .filter(x => x.match(/^fs-/))
      // stripping leading `fs-`
      .map( x => { 
        const [a,b] = x.match(/^fs-(\w+)/i); 
        return b; 
      // clicking all elements having data atribute matching the fs- classes from the collection  
      }).forEach( x => {
        console.log(x); 
        $("[data-value='${x}']").click(); 
      });
  });

  var FWP = {
    facets: {chapter:[]}, 
    is_reset: false,
    refresh: function() {}
  };
  
  $(".chapter").click(function () {
    /* clear all */
    $.each(FWP.facets, function(name, val) {FWP.facets[name] = [];});
    var [chapter] = Array.from($(this).prop('classList'))
      // filtering non 'show-' classes 
      .filter(x => x.match(/^show-/))
      // stripping leading `show-`
      .map( x => { 
        const [a,b] = x.match(/^show-(\w+)/i); 
        return b; 
      });
    /* make selection */
    FWP.facets['chapter'] = [chapter]; 
    FWP.is_reset = true; // don't parse facets
    FWP.refresh();
    console.log(FWP);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="element" class="fs-one fs-two fs-three other1 other2">Click here</div>

<hr/>
Second part (click some of the entries)
<hr/>

<div class="chapter show-book">Book</div>
<div class="chapter show-window">Window</div>
<div class="chapter show-chair">Chair</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I think you must have misunderstood the problem. It relates only to the second snippet where the first snippet was shown only to illustrate the kind of solution I was looking for. I am only looking to edit the second snippet. Am I making sense?

Comment: I've edited my answer including the second part.

Comment: Updated my question with a section 'OUTCOME' at the bottom.

Comment: I'm not sure I can help much more than I've done as I don't have the whole picture, but if you find this answer helpful you may vote it up and/or select it as best answer (green tick) if you think so.

Comment: Yes of course. I understand. Is there a way to share further information with you? Can we communicate outside of StackOverflow?

Comment: I'm just trying to help if I have some free time, which is very limited actually. I'm actually a Perl backend programmer, but JavaScript is just one of the many languages I'm able to serve pretty well. Knowing more than usual for a simple programmer I am hardly used and even sometimes abused from the company I work for :) Shortly - I'm really tiered sometimes but I'm also sure that you are able to handle this case and even be better than me. You just need some time and will to do it. Head up and fight the problems!

Comment: Oh wait!..... The issue is with the hyphenated classname. So I have .show-designs-four-a and the code is only seeing 'designs'.....It doesn't add the '-four-a' to the var. Make sense?

Comment: change `(\w+)` to include `-` i.e. `([\w\-]+)` everywhere it is present and it will work fine. `\w` does not include `-` symbol  (RegEx in case you are interested).